# discord.py - Is there some way I can get ctx from an on_message event?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, ctx

I want to recode my music bot (currently works with commands), so that a channel gets created. If you write any message in that channel, the bot is supposed to play the song from the message. For that I need to access stuff like voice_state, but on_message doesn't seem to provide that, while ctx does. Now I'm looking for any way to convert the message into a command, get ctx any other way or just access all the voice stuff somehow else.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is, you can use [Bot.get_context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_context) for this purpose. It's a coroutine.

example:

```py
@bot.listen()
async def on_message(message: discord.Message):
    ctx = await bot.get_context(message)
    command = bot.get_command('command name')
    await ctx.invoke(command, arg1, arg2, keywordarg1="something", keywordarg2="I like python")
```

Positional arguments in command followed by keyword arguments. You don't need to provide `ctx` argument as `ctx.invoke` supplies that by default during command invocation

and actually, no. You can use `message.guild.voice_client` for accessing the `voice_client`, `ctx.voice_client` is a shortcut to that. Also, for accessing author's voice state `message.author.voice`, most of the things you do in context are shortcuts to Guild/Member object methods. There are some exceptions though.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I was looking for.